# ￼Show that $\int_E f (x, y) dx$ is differentiable with respect to $y$ and $\frac{d}{dy}\int_E f(x,y)dx=\int_E \frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Assume that $f = f(x,y)$ is a function defined on $E × (a,b).$ For each fixed $y ∈ (a,b),$ $f$ is integrable with respect to $x$ on $E$, and for each fixed $x ∈ E$, $f$ is differentiable with respect to $y$ on $(a, b).$ Assume that there is a function $g ∈ L_1(E),$ such that
￼$| \frac{d}{dy} f(x,y)| ≤ g(x),$ $(x,y) ∈ E × (a,b).$
￼Show that $\int_E f (x, y) dx$ is differentiable with respect to $y$ and
$\frac{d}{dy}\int_E f(x,y)dx=\int_E \frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)dx.$

I considered using the functions $f_n(x) = n[f(x, y + n^{-1}) - f(x, y)]$.  The $f_n$ are integrable and tend to $\frac{d}{dy}f(x, y)$ which is integrable since $\leq g(x)$.  However,  all this gives me to use is Fatou since I can't dominate the $f_n$ by any functions.  Any help would be awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use the mean value theorem to dominate $f_n$

Comment: This is in the books.

Comment: Okay got it.  Thanks.